# What's happening to my tomato plants?

Tags: tomatoes, containers

I've had my tomatoes outside in approx 30cm pots for 6 weeks now. Notwithstanding a magnesium deficiency, I believe I have successfully treated with epsom salt, they seem to have been fine.

Over the last couple of weeks the lower leaves on a couple of the plants have first gradually gone completely yellow, then turn to brown and started to wither away. It starts at the leaves on the very bottom stems and gradually moves upwards. The upper leaves and fruit of the plant seem to be fine although I have noticed growth has slowed significantly.

I initially suspected overwatering, however I've reduced the watering frequency and it's made no difference.

I'm in the UK. Any pointers appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why did you think you had a magnesium deficiency in the soil?

Comment: Yellowing and then brown spotting of the lower leaves in between the veins. I obviously can't be 100% but the progression did stop after I applied Epsom salt to the leaves and soil

Comment: Have you been using proper tomato fertilizer every couple of weeks? How much sun do the plants get?

Comment: I've been using [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Vitax-ORGANIC-Super-Concentrated-Tomato/dp/B08MV6FGDC) every few weeks. The plants are against a south facing wall of my house and get sun from 0800-1800 at this time of year